# App crashing since I've added new main activity

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-xml

I've successfully added a new main activity in another project beforehand. However I've tried to use the same techniques in a different project (which was having issues due to the amount of work in the main thread).

I wanted to create a simple home page named "HomePage" with a button that brings up the original main activity named "MainActivity". "MainActivity is used to connect to a servlet called "GetLightData". This project worked (with a few bugs) on the emulator prior to adding the Homepage, but now it crashes instantly. I'd really appreciate answers specific to my code, thanks.

HomePage:

```
package com.example.clearlight;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class HomePage extends Activity {

    private Button ScheduleBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

         ScheduleBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_btn);

        ScheduleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomePage.this, MainActivity.class);
                HomePage.this.startActivity(myIntent);


            }
        });
    }   



}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.clearlight;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txt;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        setContentView(R.layout.relative);
        // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.

        /*LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        rootLayout.addView(txt);
        setContentView(rootLayout);*/


        URL url = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
        try {
            String registrationUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/SensorInfo/GetLightData?sensor=light";
            url = new URL(registrationUrl);

            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(registrationUrl);
            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // request data from server
            String result = httpclient.execute(getRequest, handler);
            Log.d("MyApp", "Data from server is "+ result);


          //Creating TextView Variable**********************************
            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

            //Sets the new text to TextView (runtime click event)//*******
            text1.setText("Light Data= " + result);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Light Data:" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //MESSAGE BOX
            //txtMessage.setText(String.valueOf(msg1) + "  " + String.valueOf(msg2));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.clearlight"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.clearlight.HomePage"
            android:label="@string/homepage" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity" >

            <!-- Move the intent filter to HomePage -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

> 03-11 18:08:09.522: I/Process(878): Sending signal. PID: 878 SIG: 9
>   03-11 18:08:14.882: E/Trace(893): error opening trace file: No such
>   file or directory (2) 03-11 18:08:15.192: D/AndroidRuntime(893):
>   Shutting down VM 03-11 18:08:15.192: W/dalvikvm(893): threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300) 03-11
>   18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-11
>   18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.clearlight/com.clearlight.HomePage}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.clearlight.HomePage 03-11
>   18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
>   03-11 18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   03-11 18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 03-11
>   18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   03-11 18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-11
>   18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-11 18:08:15.272:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(893):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 03-11
>   18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-11
>   18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-11 18:08:15.272:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(893):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   03-11 18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 03-11
>   18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-11 18:08:15.272:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(893): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.clearlight.HomePage 03-11 18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   03-11 18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 03-11
>   18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 03-11
>   18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
>   03-11 18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
>   03-11 18:08:15.272: E/AndroidRuntime(893):    ... 11 more 03-11
>   18:08:19.122: I/Process(893): Sending signal. PID: 893 SIG: 9

Comment: Can you add your logcat with the error message(s)?

Comment: Also use a Asynctask to connect your server and retrieve data. That way you get rid of memory errors.

Comment: I have added the Logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
<activity
        android:name="com.clearlight.HomePage"
        android:label="@string/homepage" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity" >

 .... />
```

to

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.clearlight.HomePage"
        android:label="@string/homepage" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity" >
 .... />
```

currently u are registering  `HomePage` Activity in `AndroidManifest` as `com.clearlight.HomePage` but your main package is `com.example.clearlight`

Comment: Thankyou very much! I didn't notice that, or realise something like that could have such a bad effect, it works now. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to! I had to wait about 10 minutes to accept- only 1 minute left. Thanks for your help though, it was driving me crazy.